# AJAX POST with CORS to API Gateway does not work

Tags: ajax

I'm getting this error message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://########.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
I tried adding add the following code with no luck:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,POST");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. The invoke URL shows the stage but you have to add the resource name, duh :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can also use npm module cors. Just fixed my problems with it.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```